# Rank order in r

Tags: r, sorting

I want to specify the no. of duplicates in order which they appear (in `R`).

Example:

```
ID      DATE
1       xxx
1       xyz
2       xxx
2       xyz
2       acd
```

What I want now is:

```
ID      DATE      Instance
1       xxx       1
1       xyz       2
2       xxx       1
2       xyz       2
2       acd       3
```

any help woudl be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do this in R and post the output? dput(head(df,10)). This will allow us to work with sample data, your current description is confusing. I don't understand the ID column at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using base r you can do something like:

```
transform(df,x=with(df,ave(id,id,FUN = function(x)1:length(x))))
  id date x
1  1  xxx 1
2  1  xyz 2
3  2  xxx 1
4  2  xyz 2
5  2  acd 3
```

Comment: thanks! what if i need to include multiple variables, i.e.: lets say ID1, ID2 & ID3?

Comment: I think you should ask that question. then you will get a satisfactory answer. As per now I don't really understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

I hope the below code helps get you on the right track!

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 date = c("xxx", "xyz", "xxx", "xyz", "acd"))
head(df)
#>   id date
#> 1  1  xxx
#> 2  1  xyz
#> 3  2  xxx
#> 4  2  xyz
#> 5  2  acd

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id   date instance
#>   <dbl> <fctr>    <int>
#> 1     1    xxx        1
#> 2     1    xyz        2
#> 3     2    xxx        1
#> 4     2    xyz        2
#> 5     2    acd        3
```